# Android BLE API : multiple Notification

Tags: android, notifications, bluetooth-lowenergy

According to google BLE Sample code , I design a android application , it's need to connect another BLE Device (TI CC2640 device), the protocol has two UUID ,
so in SampleGattAttributes.java , I add like this :

```
public static String UBI_ONGOING_INFO_SERVICE_UUID = "3d963d11-d107-4d7d-918f-61ca2aa836af";

public static String UBI_SYSTEM_INFO_SERVICE_UUID = "3d963d13-d107-4d7d-918f-61ca2aa836af";
```

now I need to read/write Characteristic
in BluetoothLeService.java:

```
public final static String EXTRA_DATA_ONGOING =
        "com.example.bluetooth.le.EXTRA_DATA_ONGOING";

public final static String EXTRA_DATA_SYSTEM_INFO =
        "com.example.bluetooth.le.EXTRA_DATA_SYSTEM_INFO";

public final static UUID UUID_UBI_ONGOING_INFO_SERVICE_UUID =
        UUID.fromString(SampleGattAttributes.UBI_ONGOING_INFO_SERVICE_UUID);

public final static UUID UUID_UBI_SYSTEM_INFO_SERVICE_UUID =
        UUID.fromString(SampleGattAttributes.UBI_SYSTEM_INFO_SERVICE_UUID);

private void broadcastUpdate(final String action,final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic){
...
...
if (UUID_UBI_SYSTEM_INFO_SERVICE_UUID.equals(characteristic.getUuid())){
  final byte[] data1 = characteristic.getValue();
  ....
  ....
  intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DATA, stringBuilder.toString());
  intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DATA_SYSTEM_INFO, strBuilder.toString());
}else{
  ...
  ...
  intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DATA, stringBuilder.toString());
  intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DATA_ONGOING, strBuilder.toString());
}


public void setCharacteristicNotification(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic,boolean enabled) {
    mBluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, enabled);

    if (UUID_UBI_SERVICE_SERVICE_UUID.equals(characteristic.getUuid())) {
        BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristic.getDescriptor(UUID.fromString(00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb));
        descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
        mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
     }

if (UUID_UBI_SYSTEM_INFO_SERVICE_UUID.equals(characteristic.getUuid())){
   BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor1 = characteristic.getDescriptor(00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb);
     descriptor1.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
     mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor1);
}
```

then , I can only receive notifications for the first characteristics. 
how can I receive notifications from both characteristics and show data 
in DeviceControlActivity.java ?

I am stuck in here for long time , hope someone can help me , thanks.

In fact , I don't need to revise broadcastUpdate function , cause 
EXTRA_DATA should be process in DeviceControlActivity.

Comment: Are you sure that you wait until the onDescriptorWrite callback is called before you enable notifications on the second characteristic? You can only have one outstanding operation at a time.

Comment: In fact , I am not wait . I am not add any delay function.

Comment: You need to wait for the callback. Otherwise it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

@Emil , like this:

```
if (UUID_UBI_SERVICE_SERVICE_UUID.equals(characteristic.getUuid())) {
    BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristic.getDescriptor(UUID.fromString(00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb));
    descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
    mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
//add sleep delay 500
try {
    Thread.sleep(500);
}catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

if (UUID_UBI_SYSTEM_INFO_SERVICE_UUID.equals(characteristic.getUuid())){
    BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor1 = characteristic.getDescriptor(00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb);
    descriptor1.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
     mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor1);
}
```

My mistakes , I should not revise Notification function.